# Scrollbar keeps popping in on reload

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

In my application I'm using vuejs with some extensions like: vuex, vue-router and more. The problem I'm having is that on every reload my application moves a bit to the left because of a scrollbar and then gets back to it's original position.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want anyone to sroll on the page, you can just add

```
.className {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I narrowed my problem down to chartjs. It first loads in a chart that is empty and really big (from 0.0 to 1) and then plots the data. I still dont know how to fix this. Help would be appreciated